# Integral of $\int_{b-a}^{a} \frac{1}{x} \sqrt{a^2-(b-x)^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am solving the integral

$$\int_{b-a}^{a} \frac{1}{x} \sqrt{a^2-(b-x)^2}dx$$

which is related to the magnetic flux of toroid with circular cross section. I got this integration but have no idea how to compute it...

Comment: Difference of squares suggests a trig substitution.

Answer (score 2):

Split the integral into three
\begin{align}
&\int_{b-a}^{a} \frac{1}{x} \sqrt{a^2-(b-x)^2}dx\\
=& \int_{b-a}^{a}\frac b{\sqrt{a^2-(b-x)^2}}+ \frac{b-x} {\sqrt{a^2-(b-x)^2} }+\frac{a^2-b^2} {x\sqrt{a^2-(b-x)^2}}\ dx\\
=& \ \bigg[b\cos^{-1}\frac{b-x}a
 + \sqrt{a^2-(b-x)^2}\\
&\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>-{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}\tan^{-1}\frac{a^2-b^2+b x}{\sqrt{b^2-a^2} \sqrt{a^2-(b-x)^2}}\bigg]_{b-a}^a\\
=&\ b\cos^{-1}\frac{b-a}a+ \sqrt{b(2a-b)}\\
&\>\>\>\>\>-{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}\bigg( \frac\pi2+\tan^{-1}\frac{a^2-b^2+ab}{\sqrt{b^2-a^2} \sqrt{b(2a-b)}}\bigg)
\end{align}
The first two integrals are straightforward and the third is evaluated via the Euler substitution.

Answer (score 0):

First apply kings rule to get:

$\int_{b-a}^{a} \frac{1}{b-x} \sqrt{a^2-x^2} dx$

Let $x = asin(u)$ and $dx = acos(u)du$

You get

$\int_{b-a}^{a} \frac{a(acos^2u)}{b-asinu}du$

I think you can proceed from here.